# read column names from excel file in c#

Tags: c#

I have to implement a file upload feature in which users are allowed to upload files containing tabular data. On uploading the file I want to find the column names of table. How can I do this?

Comment: You can do this with the use of the oledb. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/excel_using_oledb.aspx) is a link to a demo project which explains it all. or [this](http://dotnetperls.com/excel-interop) one with the help of the Interop namespace.

Answer (score 10):

@vc 74 I would like to point out some mistake in code:
Instead of having `sheetColumns.Rows`, there should be  `sheetColumns.Columns` as it was already referencing to DataColumn type.
To read all the column names existing in particular sheet of excel file, DataRow should be referenced as below:

After opening the connection, code goes like this:

```
 DataTable dt = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Columns, new object[]
{ null,null, sheetName, null });

 List<string> listColumn = new List<string>();
 foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
 {
      listColumn.Add(row["Column_name"].ToString());
 }
```

listColumn contains the column names existing in the specified sheet.

Comment: I did the same thing but its giving me the column name in Alphabetical order. Do you know how can i get the column name in the same order it is the file.?

Comment: For that, you need to play with ORDINAL_POSITION from column of row and sort accordingly.