# Reading contents from xlsx file using DocumentFormat namespace in C#

Tags: c#, xlsx, openxml-sdk

How to read rows one by one by its column name from xlsx file using C# or making use of `DocumentFormat` namespace.

Please help..!

Thanks.

Comment: Where does MySQL come into picture here?

Comment: when we read all xls data, Will put in dataset and that dataset will get inserted in one temp table.

Answer (score 0):

Look at below question. You can get the data into dataset first and then read it from there by column name. I think that's a better option than trying to figure out how to read data using column name in excel(if at all it's possible which I doubt).

[Get column name from excel worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662882/get-column-name-from-excel-worksheet)

Comment: I used this one but facing error The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Comment: Look at this link for the solution for this error. Second link works for the those who tried it. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine?forum=vstsdb

Comment: Oh I tried this Adarsh. Is there any another way to do it.I also tried another link but its giving me 1-1 cell value.Is it possible to it this into dataset . http://www.clear-lines.com/blog/post/OpenXML-reading-the-cells-of-a-workbook.aspx