# How to column names from the worksheet without using database in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

```
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];
                var columncount =worksheet.Dimension.Columns;
                
                var rowcount = worksheet.Dimension.Rows;
```

here is my code, I'm getting number of columns and rows but I want column names

Comment: put it in a datatable then loop through to get the names  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662882/get-column-name-from-excel-worksheet

Answer (score 0):

> I want column names

If the column name is in the first row, you can try the following method to get column names :

```
  var columnname = workSheet.Rows[1].Range.Value;
```

result:

[image]