# How do I copy an Excel column name to a string using OLEDB with C#?

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

Rookie here... I need to get the column name from an excel file so I can use it as a string. I'm using C# with OLEDB.

```
private void CheckFiles();
{
    OleDbConnection MyConnection;
    DataSet DtSet;
    OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand;
    string file = @"C:\Users\...path...\2015.xlsm";
    MyConnection = new OleDbConnection(@"provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" +
                            file + "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
    MyCommand = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = " + 
                            tab, MyConnection);
    MyConnection.Open();
    MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Net-informations.com");
    MyConnection.Close();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sounds really good that you are using `C#` with `OLEDB` now show us what you have thus far so that we can help or someone else can lend you more advice. post your code showing us what you have tired...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855101/read-column-names-from-excel-file-in-c-sharp

Comment: @MethodMan I'm so new to this that I couldn't tell if you're being sarcastic... hehehe... anyway, I don't have much... I added the code I have so far to the original post. Thanks!

Comment: you need  to use the `Fill` method to execute the OleDbAdapter sql command.. I will post an example on how I just tested excel on my own machine using JetProvider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";

ConnectionString = string.Format(ConnectionString, @"FullPathToExcelFile"); //my path replace with your actual file path

OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
conn.Open();

OleDbCommand cmdSelect = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", conn);
OleDbDataAdapter oleDBAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
oleDBAdapter.SelectCommand = cmdSelect;

DataSet myDataset = new DataSet();
oleDBAdapter.Fill(myDataset);
conn.Close();
```